# my for loop is not working properly in my code it keeps stopping after 1st cycle?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,n;
    int arr[10]={};
    printf("\n print all the entered elements in array");
    printf("\n enter the value of n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n element no %d",n);
        scanf("%d",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n the reversed elements are");

    for(i=n-1;i<=0;i--)
    {
        printf("\n the numbers are %d",arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

hey there this is my c program  code and i have first enter the no of elemnts as how many element i want in that array and the have to print it in reverse order and i am facing some problem with this as when my first loop starts after 1 complete cycle or after taking one input on element i=0 it stops. i dont have any idea whats going on here so pls help me..

Comment: Your continuation test is backwards.  You want `i >= 0`, not `i <= 0`, since `i` is counting down to zero.

Comment: no bro I tried that and it didn't worked its still the same

Comment: Why are you using a & here `scanf("%d",&n);` but not here `scanf("%d",arr[i]);` . What warnings is your compiler yelling at you? Why do you ignore the return value of `scanf()`? Your second loop IS broken as described by Tom. Fixing it just does not help with the issues in first loop.

Comment: @TomKarzes If OP gets through the issues with the first loop and starts appreciating your input, will you make an answer or would you allow me to incorporate into mine?

Comment: The first loop should be:  `for(i=0;i<n;i++)` and the second should be `for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)`.  It has no chance of working properly until you make both fixes.

Comment: @Yunnosch Feel to incorporate into your answer.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thanks. Done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the address of the array element, not its value.

So, change

`scanf("%d",arr[i]);`

to

`scanf("%d",&arr[i]);`

(And, for your own sake, learn to not ignore the return value of `scanf()`.)

Also, if you enter N as number of elements, then your code will need N+1 numbers entered, hoping that N+1 is less than 10.
This is because `for(i=0;i<=n;i++)` will need numbers entered for 0,1,2, ...N, because of the `<=`, you probably want `<`. You will then be asked one number less, which should fix the problem you describe. I.e. you should then see the "the reversed elements are" output after entering N elements. Your program currently seems to "stop" because it waits for another number being entered.

When you fixed that the next problem you encounter will be the one described in the comment by Tom Karzes. It prevents the output of "the numbers are".

> Your continuation test is backwards. You want i >= 0, not i <= 0, since i is counting down to zero.

This means that, with your code as is, the body of the second loop will never be executed because with any meaningful `n` value, `i<=0` for `i==n-1` will already be false for the first check and the loop is immediatly done.